# Is it possible to change Shopify code for check out fields? Apple Pay doesn't map with Shopify Checkout address fields in UAE

Tags: stripe-payments, shopify, applepay

I want to integrate enable Apple Pay with Shopify in UAE. I am using Stripe as a payment gateway, and it integrate successfully. All other payment methods work, but someone tries to pay via Apple Pay it shows the error like the attached screenshot.

Please suggest a solution to this. Thanks

[image: image of error while paying via Apple pay]

I tried integrating other payment gateways as well, but no avail. Our store is losing customers by not having apple pay.